# How to pass and save a 2D array to an object using the constructor

Tags: c++

There are a lot of solutions available for passing 2D arrays to an function, but I can not figure out how to assign that array to my object in the constructor. Any help would be appreciated.

I have an array of bytes:

```
int demo1_rows = 9;
int demo1_id[9] = { 0x0A1, 0x0A2, 0x0A0, 0x0A1, 0x0A2, 0x0A0, 0x0A1, 0x0A2, 0x0A0 };
uint8_t demo1[9][8] = {
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3, 0x00, 0xC3, 0x00, 0xC3},
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB9, 0x00, 0xB9, 0x00, 0xB9},
  {0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA5, 0x00, 0xA5, 0x00, 0xA5},
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAF, 0x00, 0xAF, 0x00, 0xAF},
  {0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB4, 0x00, 0xB4, 0x00, 0xB4},
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB4, 0x00, 0xB4, 0x00, 0xB4},
  {0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
};
```

My object:

```
Program Demo1(demo1, demo1_id, demo1_size);
```

My Class:

```
class Program
{
private:
    uint8_t **program;
    int *id;
    int arraySize;
public:
    Program(uint8_t func[][8], int new_id[], int size) {
        program = func;
        id = new_id;
        arraySize = size;
    }
}
```

There is an error when trying to assign func to program.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not array. The argument is a pointer to an array with eight elements, not a pointer to a pointer. Use the proper type for the member: `uint8_t (*program)[8]`.

Comment: or proper type `std::vector<std::array<uint8_t,8>>`

Comment: `uint8_t func[][8]` is a `uint8_t [][8]`, a pointer to an array, not  a `uint8_t **`, a pointer to a pointer. Remember that arrays decay to pointers but they aren't pointers.

Comment: @idclev463035818 The opposite: `std::vector<std::array<uint_8, 8>>`

Comment: @Eugene ups, edited

Comment: Otherwise `uint8_t (*program)[8];` to create a *Pointer-to-Array* of `uint8_t [8]`. If you are not memory limited such as programming for a micro-controller, etc.., then the `std::vector` approach is the normal choice.

Comment: ... in fact, better use [this](https://godbolt.org/z/nfxahc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fix your current code, with minimal changes, and store the multidimentional array as a reference, you can do this:

typedef the array type, and store it as a reference. Then use the member initializer list in the constructor to take the reference and assign it. This will be similar to storing the pointer to the entire array.

```
#include <stdint.h>

int demo1_rows = 9;
int demo1_id[9] = { 0x0A1, 0x0A2, 0x0A0, 0x0A1, 0x0A2, 0x0A0, 0x0A1, 0x0A2, 0x0A0 };
uint8_t demo1[9][8] = {
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3, 0x00, 0xC3, 0x00, 0xC3},
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB9, 0x00, 0xB9, 0x00, 0xB9},
  {0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA5, 0x00, 0xA5, 0x00, 0xA5},
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAF, 0x00, 0xAF, 0x00, 0xAF},
  {0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB4, 0x00, 0xB4, 0x00, 0xB4},
  {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB4, 0x00, 0xB4, 0x00, 0xB4},
  {0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
};

typedef uint8_t MyArray[9][8];

class Program
{
private:
   MyArray& program;
   int* id;
   int arraySize;
public:
   Program(MyArray& func, int new_id[], int size)
      : program (func)
   {
      id = new_id;
      arraySize = size;

      // you can now access program[3][3] etc
   }

};

int main()
{
   Program p(demo1, demo1_id, demo1_rows);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a newer student programmer and this is for a microcontroller so trying to avoid extra libraries and keep it simple.

Comment: I don't think you are adding an extra library here, the only addition is `typedef` and references, those are true native c++

Comment: I accidentally added iostream while I was testing, removed that for you in the edit

Comment: Sorry I meant in reference to minimal changes and avoid using something like vectors. I figured out I did not need iostream and implemented the changes your showed me, it works now thanks.

Comment: No problem, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.